# Why the fatal error is coming even after including proper namespaces?

Tags: php, exception, fatal-error, pushwoosh

Following is my program written to send push-notifications using php-pushwoosh library:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Client\Pushwoosh;
use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Model\Request\CreateMessageRequest;
use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Model\Notification\Notification;
use Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Exception;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

/*require('../config.php');
require('../common.php');*/

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$auth_token = $data['auth_token'];
$app_code   = $data['app_code'];
$page_no    = $data['page_no'];
$page_total = $data['page_total'];

define('PW_AUTH', $auth_token);
define('PW_APPLICATION', $app_code);

// Create a Pushwoosh client
$pushwoosh = Pushwoosh::create()
    ->setApplication(PW_AUTH)
    ->setAuth(PW_APPLICATION);

if(!empty($page_no) && !empty($page_total)) {

  if (!Phpfox::isUser()) {
    $flag = false;
    $response["error"] = "error";
    $response["message"] = "Please login";
    echoRespnse(401, $response);

  } else {    

    $notificaions = Phpfox::getService('notification')->getAllNotifications($page_no,$page_total);

    if(!empty($notificaions)) {
      $notificaions = walk_recursive_remove($notificaions, 'unset_null_children');
      for($i=0;$i<count($notificaions);$i++) {
        $notificaions[$i]['message'] = stripslashes(strip_tags($notificaions[$i]['message']));
        $notificaions[$i]['profile_image'] = image_creator($notificaions[$i]['user_image']);
      }
      $notifications_data = json_encode($notifications);      
    } 
  }  
} else {
  $notifications_data = "Error in request";
}   

// Create a request for the '/createMessage' Web Service
$request = CreateMessageRequest::create()
    ->addNotification(Notification::create()->setContent($notifications_data));

// Call the REST Web Service
$response = $pushwoosh->createMessage($request);

// Check if its ok
if($response->isOk()) {
  print 'Great, my message has been sent !';
} else {
  print 'Oops, the sent failed :-( '; 
  print 'Status code : ' . $response->getStatusCode()." ";
  print 'Status message : ' . $response->getStatusMessage();
}
?>
```

After executing it on the server I got following fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Exception`\PushwooshException' with message 'None of the 'application' or 'applicationsGroup' properties are set !' in /var/www/api/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/vendor/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/src/main/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/Pushwoosh.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/api/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/push_notifications.php(61): Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Client\Pushwoosh->createMessage(Object(Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Model\Request\CreateMessageRequest)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/api/gomoob-php-pushwoosh/vendor/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/src/main/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/Pushwoosh.php on line 106`
```

If you want to check the hierarchy of name spaces I included you can check at this [php-pushwoosh namespace hierarchy](http://gomoob.github.io/php-pushwoosh/phpdocumentor/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a link to the Pushwoosh [source](https://github.com/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/blob/master/src/main/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/Pushwoosh.php#L98) maybe looking at how that method behaves will help you debug. I think your issue lies with your Pushwoosh instantiation. I would verify that PW_AUTH actually has some data it in, it's possible it could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You problem in this lines, because PW_AUTH & PW_APPLICATION are not defined.

```
// Create a Pushwoosh client
$pushwoosh = Pushwoosh::create()
    ->setApplication(PW_AUTH)
    ->setAuth(PW_APPLICATION);
```

You must define PW_AUTH & PW_APPLICATION constants, also you must swap it and for setAuth use PW_APPLICATION